# Optimizing the algorithm to run under 4 seconds for a quite large number of operations

Tags: algorithm, kotlin, optimization, input, console

I have the following code which is for solving the [practise challanges from hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/crush/problem).

And there are literally 10^7 values to be created in a list and then each should be incremented according to 10^5 queries (with console read time included), I need to crack it within 4 seconds. [Here](https://gist.github.com/Animeshz/ddf34186d6d987eca9c9642fdeced4f1) is total inputs (with queries).

First line contains two numbers, first(n) is the number of values in list, second(m) is the number of queries following below. All lines below are queries have 3 numbers, first(a) and second(b) is the indexes (starting from 1), third(k) is the value to be added into the list within the indexes. And then finally the maximum in the list should be console ouput.

```kotlin
private fun readLn() = readLine()!! // string line
private fun readStrings() = readLn().split(" ") // list of strings
private fun readInts() = readStrings().map { it.toInt() } // list of ints

fun main() {
    val (n, m) = readInts()

    val list = MutableList(n) { 0L }
    repeat(m) {
        val queries = readStrings()
        val a = queries[0].toInt() - 1
        val b = queries[1].toInt() - 1
        val k = queries[2].toLong()

        for (i in a..b) {
            list[i] += k
        }
    }

    println(list.max())
}
```

Currently it seems well optimized for me, but still can't do all the operations within 4 seconds.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance!

---

#### Edit - After answer provided by @Photon, I've modified the code but still with that algorithm as well the time limit is reached for same test cases.

Here is the modified code -

```kotlin
private fun readLn() = readLine()!! // string line
private fun readStrings() = readLn().split(" ") // list of strings
private fun readInts() = readStrings().map { it.toInt() } // list of ints

fun main() {
    val (n, m) = readInts()

    val list = MutableList(n + 2) { 0L }
    repeat(m) {
        val queries = readStrings()
        val a = queries[0].toInt()
        val b = queries[1].toInt()
        val k = queries[2].toLong()

        list[a] += k
        list[b + 1] -= k
    }

    for (i in 1..n + 1) {
        list[i] = list[i - 1] + list[i]
    }

    println(list.max())
}
```

Comment: I think, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place for this question...

Comment: @din1st ya you're correct its better suit there but anyway questions regarding algorithms are on-topic and none of the off-topic points are pointed in the question as mentioned in here https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic :)

Comment: I didn't say anything about off topic and I didn't vote to close this question but you might get better answers there.

Comment: You can get all the answers you need just by searching for `hackerrank crush`

Comment: @user3386109 where (especially kotlin)?

Comment: The search box at the top of this page. And language is irrelevant. Once you understand the algorithm, the implementation in any language (that you know) is easy.

Comment: @user3386109 for the new algorithm suggested by Photon as well as you, the time limit is still reached, you can try to submit and check as guest in hackerrank the code in edited question. (but it seems to complete in 2.2s in my local computer with i3-5th gen, don't know how their 4 second has reached).

Comment: If the time limit is being reached, then the question is where is the time being used. Could be the input operations in the `repeat(m)` loop. Could also be in the `for` loop or the `max` function. Since `m` can only be 10^5, but `n` can be 10^7, the input operations would need to be really slow to be the problem. So let's assume it's not the `repeat(m)` loop. You can improve by combining the `for` loop and `max` computation. You also don't need to update the list. Something like `val total = list[1], best = list[1] for (i in 2..n+1){ total = total + list[i] if (total > best) best = total }`

Comment: @user3386109 thanks, that helped in some of test cases!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brute force is simply too slow no matter how much you optimize this. Here`s a simple array trick to solve this in O(N + Q) time:

1. First we have array of zeroes of size `N+2`: `A = [0, 0, 0, 0, ..., 0]`
2. For query `L R K` instead of increasing all numbers in interval we can increase first one by `K` and `R+1` one by `-K`
3. then after all queries we can modify array by adding `A[i-1]` for all `i` in `[1, N]`
4. this will be the same as doing all queries

It might be confusing so here's an example:

- `N=5` so our initial array: `A = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`
- lets say we have a query: `1 3 3`
- updated array: `A = [0, 3, 0, 0, -3, 0, 0]`
- lets say we have another query: `2 5 10`
- updated array: `A = [0, 3, 10, 0, -3, 0, -10]`
- now after all queries we can add `A[i-1]` for all `i` in `[1, 5]`
- updated array: `A = [0, 3, 13, 13, 10, 10, 0]`
- notice is`s the same as doing all queries by brute force

Comment: Still it seems to not complete in the time :(

Comment: @Animesh Sahu Described approach is extremely fast. Perhaps your implementation has some slow pieces (data input?)

Comment: @MBo in my poor system with i3-5th gen it runs in around 2200 ms, while hackerrank says time limit reached in the same test-cases failed previously don't know why their time limit of 4s reached.

Comment: 2200 ms is too much. I'd expect tens of milliseconds

Comment: @MBo lemme test the average time taken to read inputs, using the std-lib function `readLine()`

Comment: @MBo it takes 60 us or 0.06 ms to read from console on an average!

Comment: @AnimeshSahu try using default code for read given by hackerrank

Comment: @sidgate takes the same time!

Comment: @sidgate any guess why's it happening?

Comment: @AnimeshSahu Kotlin standart Input/Output is simply too slow for such large amount of data, you can google around for some fast I/O templates like https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/71089 and try that out

Comment: @Photon even after using BufferedReader from java, exact tests failed previously they failed again :(

Comment: Anyway its the correct way (algorithm) so I've accepted the answer!